# Unable to deserialize using ObjectMapper when Object has multiple constructors

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am getting the following error while deserialising the object .

```
(no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

My Object Definition is

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    @Document(collection = "abc")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ABC implements Serializable {
    
      @Id
      private String id;
      @Indexed
      private String number;
      private String a;
      private Long b;
      //added later 
      private String c;
      public ABC(Long b) {
        this.b=b;
      }
      public ABC(String a,Long b) {
        this.b=b;
        this.a=a;
      }
      //added later
      public ABC(String a,Long b,String c) {
        this.b=b;
        this.a=a;
        this.c=c;
     }
  }
```

I was using `objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ABC>() {})` to convert json to ABC object . It was working fine before adding variable c and the new constructor. I have to add a new consturctor to maintain compatibility with exisiting code. After adding variable c it is throwing the above error. I was able to deserialize `{"id":"123","a":"example","b":1}`. I was unable to deserialize `{"id":"123","a":"example","b":1,"c":"ex2"}` . Does objectMapper in Jackson use custom constructor or default constructor with setters for deserialisations .

Comment: Probably putting `JsonCreator` over the new constructor can help, please include json examples  you cannot deserialize.

Comment: @dariosicily I have added the json in which issue was faced. I have tried `JsonCreator` with `JsonProperty` and it did not help faced the same issue .

Comment: value of 'b' is of type Long. In the example JSON, its 'ex1'. can you try changing that?

Comment: I tried both jsons and they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to the party, but this may help someone.

As of version 2.15.2, the `@JsonProperty` can be used in the constructor params as well as in random vars in your class, however, if you do use `@JsonCreator` on a constructor, then you **must** annotate the constructor params with `@JsonProperty` to deserialize (*unless you also create your custom deserializer, but that's outside the scope of the question*).

Also you don't need to use `TypeReference` in your case.
You would want to use `TypeReference` if your class was defined with generics like `ABC<T>`. Then you'd use `TypeReference<ABC<T>>`.

Otherwise you can just: `objectMapper.readValue(json, ABC.class)`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your test with Jackson 2.15.2 and it worked fine. As is. I was able to deserialize your String `{"id":"123","a":"example","b":1,"c":"ex2"}` into your ABC class. Just small changes that I did - I don't use lomboc so I added to your class getters and setters and all args constructor and no args constructor and `toString()` method. Here is the code I ran:

```
    ABC abc = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString("{\"id\":\"123\",\"a\":\"example\",\"b\":1,\"c\":\"ex2\"}", ABC.class);
    System.out.println(abc);
```

Here is the output:

```
ABC{id='123', number='null', a='example', b=1, c='ex2'}
```

Just to clarify - class JsonUtils is a thin wrapper over ObjectMapper class. This class comes with Open Source MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. You can try it if you want. Here is [JsonUtils javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html), and the library could be obtained as [maven artifact from Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and javadoc)